# Citations in Bold

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

Please, I add this code in my manuscript, but my citations are separated by `;` instead of `,` (for example \cite{A1,A2} generates [A1; A2] but not [A1, A2]).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbold{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\AtBeginBibliography{
     \DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{#1}
     \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mknumalph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite[43]{geer} ipsum.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Please ask about the new issue in a new question**. There is nothing in the code that would try to produce something like "[A1, Theorem 1]", there is only code that (successfully) produces "[**Gee85**, p. 43]".

Comment: You may also want to look into adding `%` at the end of lines in your `\AtBeginBibliography` block. (So `\AtBeginBibliography{%` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{#1}%`) to avoid spurious spaces.

Comment: Regarding your second question (now edited out): Do you use bibtex or biber as your bibliography backend? Recent `biblatex` versions expect biber, so if you use the default bibtex, the above code obviously won't work correctly. Either [configure your editor to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751) or add `backend=bibtex` to biblatex settings (so in your example it would be `\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`).

Comment: Please there is another method to make  the citation bold without the above code? (\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}).

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of `\*citedelim` macros available (see the `biblatex` manual).

In your example to get a comma with `\cite{A1,A2}` you want to add

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

to your preamble.